# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https

I'm developing a website with C# .Net. The site was originally developed for http (port 88), and now it was requested https (port 443). I have applied a SSL certificate.

I've installed the certificate on IIS7 and I can access the site, but, `<a href='<% url.action("x","person") %>' ...` fails. It returns the error ***"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80"***.

Why am I receiving the error?

Comment: does your url start with `https`? seems like you use the default `http` port 80.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things.  But hit the same issue a couple of weeks ago and it was because we were still allowing http in the settings.

For the site, under advanced settings, verify that you only have "https" in the allowed protocols.

Answer (score 0):

ensure you didn't "stop" IIS and forget to start it again